# how to start scheduling tasks

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-task, scheduling

"How to start a different task when other task stops" in windows xp.By using task scheduler it has to happen. either programmetically or through command line.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make the "if done, then start" logic within the task executable itself. Meaning, schedule a task that calls a batch file, VB script or PowerShell script. That script will call the command that you want (for example, `ntbackup`, `robocopy`, whatever it is that you're doing) and then on the last line it will call `schtasks.exe` to trigger the next command.

Other than that, there is no built-in capability to call another task upon successful completion of one within Windows XP (that I am aware of).

Comment: No command is there to do my work?

Comment: @abcdefgh - I think Wes's last sentence pretty much sums it up: `...there is no built-in capability to call another task upon successful completion of one within Windows XP`

Comment: yaya k thank you.. i will try to work on it. thanks again

Comment: can u give the script with any 2 task names let us say "task1,task2".